# Where does Android Studio save the ProGuard mapping file?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, proguard

In Android Studio, where are the ProGuard mapping files generated after compiling a signed APK?

I'm not sure if it isn't working or if I just forgot the file path, and my compulsory Google/Stack Overflow search did not answer this

Comment: it is explained here officially 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#uploading_proguard_mapping_files_manually

Comment: @JayakrishnanPM glad to see Google got around to it 3 years later.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

It should be located at `build/outputs/proguard/release/mapping.txt` in your application module's directory.

In the latest version of ProGuard and Android Studio, the file is located at `build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt`.

Comment: More information about the generated files and path: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: If your **Instant Run** is enabled, you may not be able to see mapping file. Disable Instant Run and build again.

Comment: After an update to Gradle 6.2.2/Gradle Plugin 3.6.1 the paths changed for us.
`/app/build/outputs/mapping/brandExampleEnvProductionRelease/mapping.txt`
`/app/build/outputs/mapping/brandExampleEnvIntegrationBeta/mapping.txt` are the new paths.

Comment: UPDATE: As of AS 4.1.1 , Gradle plugin 4.0.2 , Gradle 6.1.1 , you need to have ```minifyEnabled true``` to get mapping.txt inside the ```build/outputs/mapping/<FLAVOUR>/mapping.txt```

Comment: how to add this path in bitrise.yml file?

Answer (score 80):

For me they are at `'build/outputs/mapping/release'`

Comment: 'build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt'

Comment: Yes that one is perfect for android studio 2.3.2

Comment: app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt bc there was a separate build folder that did not contain the mapping file...

Answer (score 43):

I found it cleaner to configure proguard to write the mapping.txt file to a location outside of the `build/` directory tree, so that it could be more conveniently checked into version control.

To achieve this, put this in your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

This will (most likely) place it in the same directory as your `proguard-rules.pro` file. Ultimately, you probably want to write it to the same directory as your APK file and with an equivalent name (which might include flavor, build type etc).

Note: in my experience, this is *not* overruled by the proguard template file (which was suggested by a commenter to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431637/444761) here).

UPDATE: If you have multiple product flavors, then this is a much better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31116608/444761

Comment: This is better than my solution, as like you say you can then place it under version control.

Comment: why would you like to version control this one? you need it for every APK you release seperately as it is build dependant. as you have to upload / checkin such an apk seperately from source there is actually no need to check it in the source VCS!?

Comment: @Denny1989 not sure what you mean. I build an APK and store it outside version control. I have to keep the mapping file somewhere. I *could* store it alongside the APK, but I find it cleaner to version control it. However, I only have one release APK per project so YMMV.

Answer (score 41):

I found that it was not being generated, so I added this to the rules file

```
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

Comment: I found that printmapping was overruled by a template proguard file I was using!

Comment: this worked and generated all the proguard output files for me.

Comment: Still no mapping directory. Maybe it's because V8 ignores progurad now? How to generate it with V8?

Answer (score 19):

Its quite late to answer this question but just in case someone need my answer.

**Location of Mapping file to deobfuscate:**

> ProGuard saves the file in the app
>   **app/build/outputs/mapping/FLAVOR/release/mapping.txt**

Generally in debug mode you don't need the mapping file because there generally obfuscation is disabled.
If it is not that case then make sure in build.gradle file you have below code for debug variant.

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled false
    debuggable true
}
```

**Some Gotchas:**

mapping.txt file gets overwritten every time you create a release build with ProGuard, so first take backup of that file before creating a new release. It will help to obfuscated stack trace from an older version of your app.

Apart from that there are two ways to obfuscate your code :

**1. Upload your mapping.txt file to Google play Console:**

When publishing your app on Google Play, you can upload the mapping.txt file for each version of your APK. Then Google Play will deobfuscate incoming stack traces from user-reported issues so you can review them in the Google Play Console.

**2. Use local sdk tool retrace.sh/retrace.bat:**

Some times you want to run the release version of your app(by changing build variant to release and running it) to cross check and fix the errors so that it does not happens in production ( when released to play-store).

To convert an obfuscated stack-trace to a readable one yourself, use the retrace script (**retrace.bat on Windows; retrace.sh on Mac/Linux**).

It is located in the `<sdk-root>/tools/proguard/bin/` directory.

`<sdk-root>` is the place where your all android libraries and sdks were installed.

The script takes the mapping.txt file and your stack trace, producing a new, readable stack trace.

**Command Syntax:**

```
retrace.bat|retrace.sh [-verbose] mapping.txt [<stacktrace_file>]
```

**For example:**

```
retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt
```

I prefer local version of obfuscating as is quite handy to pre-check production errors.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Here it is in a picture - you will find it in the mapping folder:

Answer (score 13):

I am using version **Android Studio 2.2.2**. For me it's located in the following locations:

For debug:
**`\app\build\outputs\mapping\debug\mapping.txt`**

For release:
**`\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\mapping.txt`**

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is still searching for mapping.txt:

minifyEnabled in build.gradle has to be set to true

I'm using Android Studio 4.2 Beta 4 and the standard-setting was false.

If minifyEnable is set to false the build is not "minified", so a mapping-file is of course not necessary, but google-play-console asks for the mapping file anyway.

... Very confusing for a beginner

Comment: I used to think Apple's upload process was complicated unnecessarily, before Google garbage.

Comment: Absoutely, I understand this is confusing but there is a reason why mapping file is generated only for `minifyenabled=true`. It works like a Key for locked refrences. When `minifyEnabled = false` nothing is locked anyway so why create a key?

Answer (score 3):

**Android Studio and ProGuard mapping file**

[[Proguard]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285427/4770877)

Proguard outputs are located:

```
<module_name>/build/outputs/mapping/<buildType>/
//e.g.
/Users/alex/Desktop/MyProject/MyModule/build/outputs/mapping/releasefree
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I'm dumb and get lost even when somebody tells me where the file is:

```
cd StudioProjects/fooProject
find . -name "mapping.txt" | xargs less
```