# Append version number into proguard mapping folder

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I am able to auto rename my apk files in gradle.build using

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName", "MyAppName-$versionName")
```

Is there a similar method to automatically append the proguard mapping folder name with the version number?

Currently, the folder defaults to

> ...\app\build\outputs\mapping\release or debug

I am wondering if it is possible to create the mapping folders to something like `release-1.0.1` or `debug-1.0.1`.

Comment: I got to know that we can change the apk name programatically by your question .Thanks :)

Comment: if you can it will be written somewhere in the docs here: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#obfuscationoptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following[¹](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31116608/1893766) will rename `mapping.txt` to `mapping-release-1.0.1.txt` in the same folder.

In the module `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    // lots of gradle code

    // The following portion renames the mapping.txt file.
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
            variant.assemble.doLast {
                variant.mappingFile.renameTo(file(
                    "${variant.mappingFile.parent}/mapping-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.txt"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may also use `variant.versionCode` or other options in the file name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can write a method that do the renaming by copying the files to directories based on the current version. something similar to the answer here:
[How to change the proguard mapping file name in gradle for Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948538/how-to-change-the-proguard-mapping-file-name-in-gradle-for-android-project)