# Android ProGuard multiple mapping files for split APKs?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I am successfully generating signed APKs in Android studio, splitting them by ABI and assigning a different versionCode for each, by adding the following code to my `build.gradle` file:

```
// Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
ext.abiCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "arm64-v8a":2, "x86":3, "x86_64":4]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ext.abiCodes + variant.versionCode. In this example, variant.versionCode
// is equal to defaultConfig.versionCode. If you configure product flavors that
// define their own versionCode, variant.versionCode uses that value instead.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    // Assigns a different version code for each output APK
    // other than the universal APK.
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // Stores the value of ext.abiCodes that is associated with the ABI for this variant.
        def baseAbiVersionCode =
                // Determines the ABI for this variant and returns the mapped value.
                project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

        // Because abiCodes.get() returns null for ABIs that are not mapped by ext.abiCodes,
        // the following code does not override the version code for universal APKs.
        // However, because we want universal APKs to have the lowest version code,
        // this outcome is desirable.
        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {

            // Assigns the new version code to versionCodeOverride, which changes the version code
            // for only the output APK, not for the variant itself. Skipping this step simply
            // causes Gradle to use the value of variant.versionCode for the APK.
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    baseAbiVersionCode + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use ProGuard (`minifyEnabled true`) to obfuscate my code. As stated in the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#decoding), it is important to keep the `mapping.txt` files for each APK you release in order to decrypt a crash report's obfuscated stack trace received via the Google Play Developer Console. But when I generate the APKs split by ABI, I only find one `mapping.txt` file in the `<module-name>/build/outputs/mapping/release/` directory.

**My question:** Could someone please confirm that this single `mapping.txt` file will allow me to decode obfuscated stack traces for the 4 APKs which were split by ABI? If not, how can I generate the 4 different mapping files?

I tried generating the different mapping files based on a snippet I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948538/how-to-change-the-proguard-mapping-file-name-in-gradle-for-android-project/31116608#31116608), essentially trying to copy and rename the `mapping.txt` files as they are created during the multi APK generation process but I still only get one single mapping file:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            copy {
                from variant.mappingFile
                into "${rootDir}/proguardTools"
                rename { String fileName ->
                    "mapping-${variant.name}.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am very new to gradle and I find its syntax quite confusing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `Could someone please confirm that this single mapping.txt file will allow me to decode obfuscated stack traces for the 4 APKs which were split by ABI?` Why won't you try to deobfuscate?

Comment: @azizbekian That's what I ended up doing when I realised that I did not have to deploy a test version of the app to the play store to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up testing the stack trace deobfuscation with Firebase Crash Reporting (i.e. without having to deploy a crash test version of my app to the google play store) and I can confirm that *the one `mapping.txt` file created when generating the signed APKs in Android Studio does correctly deobfuscate stack traces for crashes occurring on APKs corresponding to different ABI types*.