# Customizing the bundle file name when building with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, bundle

I'm aware of this for APKs:

[How to change the proguard mapping file name in gradle for Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948538/how-to-change-the-proguard-mapping-file-name-in-gradle-for-android-project)

However none of the proposed methods work for the new Bundle `.aab` format. Any idea how to get it to work?