# How to download mapping files from play console

Tags: android, proguard, google-play-console

I lost the mapping.txt file for my app and I can't see a way to download it from the play console. Is there a way to download the mapping file?[image]

Comment: Show your research effort

Comment: @Daniel There is no effort can be done here!!! , there is no similar questions, there is no any download button anywhere :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get ProGuard mapping file of previous release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233694/how-to-get-proguard-mapping-file-of-previous-release-build)