# Unable to deobfuscate stacktrace with proguard mapping file

Tags: android, proguard, appcenter

I am using the proguard GUI to deobfuscate a stack trace on Mac. On a local test build, I can successfully deobfuscate a test crash/handled exception. But on my prod version, built on pipeline, the generated mapping file  is not able to deobfuscate the stack trace that is recorded on AppCenter. When I open the mapping file, it looks correct in structure. Google play store is able to deobfuscate crash logs. The fastlane code I used to get the mapping file is:

```
mapping_txt_output_path = "#{Actions.lane_context[SharedValues::GRADLE_MAPPING_TXT_OUTPUT_PATH]}"
```

The mapping file output path matches what I would expect based on logs.
There are no sub-modules. When I run the build commands locally, the 2 generated mapping files are the same.

I have also tried to upload the mapping file to AppCenter under the correct version name/code, but that also did not work.

I also downloaded the play store original .aab, and got the proguard mapping file as per:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403741/5208205,
but this also could not deobfuscate the stack trace.

I then did a text diff on the play store mapping file, and one generated locally from a bundle created based on the git tag commit, and they are identical.

Any ideas?