# Proguard rules for AndroidX AppCompat package

Tags: android, proguard, android-appcompat, android-proguard, androidx

Up till now I am using AppCompat libraries but now I have migrated my project to AndroidX libraries.

I am stuck with proguard rules for **androidx.**

As you know we are using proguard rules for AppCompat as below:

```
-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

I have searched a lot but didn't found any proper docs for that.

Is there any update in AndroidX Proguard rules?

Comment: I think you just need to replace `android.support.v7` by `androidx.appcompat` and For ActionProvider Use `androidx.core.view.ActionProvider` . And `androidx.appcompat.widget` in place of `android.support.v7.internal.widget` .. My point is just follow the mapping and [see the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724645/where-does-android-studio-save-the-proguard-mapping-file) .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AppCompat already contains the ProGuard rules it needs directly in the AAR: there's no need to declare any special ProGuard rules.

Therefore, you can just remove your custom rules entirely.