# How to analyze and debug ANR in a flutter app?

Tags: debugging, flutter, android-anr-dialog

I have a bunch of ANR reports in my Google Play Console for my Flutter App. How do I figure out which line in my flutter app is causing the issue as the only line numbers I see in the report are for the Java files. Is there a way we can trace these back to the actual flutter files?

Following is a sample of the code from the ANR report:

```
"main" tid=1 Native
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x753d2890 self=0x7784c14c00
  | sysTid=5725 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x780af11550
  | state=S schedstat=( 783263348209 325919126195 1054920 ) utm=51688 stm=26637 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd6d7f000-0x7fd6d81000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=

  #00  pc 000000000001f2ac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)

  #01  pc 00000000000d7e50  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)

  #02  pc 0000000000333fdc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallObjectMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+556)

  #03  pc 00000000000f896c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::dispatchVsync(long, int, unsigned int)+48)

  #04  pc 0000000000050a14  /system/lib64/libandroidfw.so (android::DisplayEventDispatcher::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+164)

  #05  pc 0000000000014ff8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+836)

  #06  pc 0000000000014c18  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+60)

  #07  pc 000000000012b348  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+44)

  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)

  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:326)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:190)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7276)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)

  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:575)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:903)
```

Answer (score 2):

After building app bundle, you'll find the mapping file here: `/app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` (assuming you have `minifyEnabled true`)

Then you'll need to upload the mapping file into the Play Console.

Play Console > App bundle explorer > On the top right click artifact and select the latest version that you just uploaded > Then go to the downloads tab > Scroll down to the assets tab > Upload it to "ReTrace mapping file" via the upload button on the right

Comment: is  `/build/app/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` true ?

Comment: There are a few places it could be. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25732793/1759443