# How to make the error title and stacktrace in firebase crashlytics readable?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, crashlytics, deobfuscation

For my Flutter Android app, error title and stacktrace of some of the error reports are not readable as the following. Especially non fatal errors that are automatically reported.

[image: Unreadable or obfuscated error message]

[image: Unreadable or obfuscated error message details]

In contrast, the stacktrace of the error reports that are manually reported using `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError` method and crash reports, are readable.

Here is the content of my proguard-rules.pro file.

```
## Flutter wrapper
 -keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.plugin.** { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.util.** { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.view.** { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.** { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.plugins.** { *; }
 -keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
 -dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**
 -ignorewarnings
 -keep class io.grpc.** { *; }
```

Comment: Proguard creates a mapping file that can be used to reverse obfuscation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724645/where-does-android-studio-save-the-proguard-mapping-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, when I remove this line `extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate` from this file `android/gradle.properties`, the problem is solved and the new errors reported to crashlytics become deobfuscated and readable.

Comment: It looks like this is now supported: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=flutter#add-sdk